# In HighStock, linking secondary yAxis to master yAxis can cause secondary values to be cropped outside the chart

Tags: highcharts

Simplifying my story, consider 2 series where I link their yAxes. In other words on the second yAxis there is a property `linkedTo: 0`

So the first yAxis is the master, hence sets extremes for both series.

However sometimes the second series has high values which are too high to be plotted in the visible area and so they get cropped.

To make matters worse, when the yAxes are linked to each other, the legend doesn't play ball: clicking on the master series name in the legend will hide both series. Clicking on the secondary series name will hide none.

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zYpcm/13/) - values on the right are cropped, legend functionality is broken.

What am I missing? How can I get both series to scale together and be all visible? How do I get the legend to work as expected? (click on series name should toggle it)

Thanks!

**EDIT**: As it turns out, if I remove `yAxis.id` ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zYpcm/14/)) the chart and legend work as expected. However linking series to yAxis based on position in the array (I think?) instead of by some ID (string) sounds less than ideal.

Ideas?

Comment: Could you recreate your issue in the jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zYpcm/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are trying assigning second series to axis which is just `copy` of proper one? I advice to set both series to master yAxis, and second yAxis use just as extra info on the right side of a chart.

Otherwise I don't understand the purpose of linking second axis to get THE SAME extremes as master yAxis, and then expecting to scale that yAxis according to series you have attached to that yAxis.

Something like this I think is better approach, see: http://jsfiddle.net/zYpcm/15/

```
        series: [{
            name: 'master',
            data: self.masterData,
            yAxis: 'master'
        }, {
            name: 'secondary',
            data: self.secondaryData,
            //yAxis: 'secondary'
        }],

        yAxis: [{
            id: 'master'
        }, {
            id: 'secondary',
            opposite: true,
            linkedTo: 0
        }]
```

Comment: How does the second series get linked to the first yAxis? To me it looks as if secondary **series** is linked to second **yAxis** (without yAxis indicated in the series, I assume they are linked by having the same position in the array?) and that second **yAxis** is `linkedTo` the first **yAxis**.
Put in other words, in your solution I can't see the value of `yAxis: 'master'`

Comment: No, if you don't specify `yAxis: index/id` all series are linked to first yAxis. Of course, you can remove `yAxis: 'master'` it's unnecessary there.